# Straight distance between two towns

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

[image]

The map shows the distance of four towns as shown in the figure. Compare quantity A with quantity B.

A: Straight distance between Austen and Seburg

B: Straight distance between Coaltown and Woodland

Is quantity B always greater than quantity A?

What I think is that if Austen=A, Coaltown=C, Seburg=S and Woodland=W then |18-x|< AS< |18+s| and |19-x|< CW< |19+x|. So, AS and CW can vary. But, my instinct says CW>AS.

Comment: May one assume as diagram suggests that top and bottom segments labeled 18km and 19km are parallel to each other?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is NOT always.

[image]

If C’ is the point on AW such that $CC’ \bot SW$, then CC’ is the shortest, and any other lines (like CW) will be longer that CC’ and hence longer than AS.

---

[image]

However, if we shift the whole  SW line left one unit such that $CW \bot SW$, then CW is the shortest, and any other lines (like CC’) will be longer that CW and hence AS = CC’ will be longer.

Answer (score 1):

Mark a point $P$ 1 km to the west of $W$, so that it's 18 km from $S$.  (I'm assuming $AC$ is always parallel to $SW$.)  By the symmetry of the picture, $|AS|=|CP|$.  Now we can see that $|CW| >|CP|=|AS|$.

Comment: But in some cases W will be so nearly directly under C=Coaltown but on one side of it, and then CW can be less than CP.

Answer (score 0):

If $a$ is the length CS and $t$ the angle ACS = angle WSC, then the squared distances, using the law of cosines, of CW and AS are respectivelty
$$ (CW)^2=a^2-38a \cos t+361,\\ 
(AS)^2=a^2-36 a \cos t +324.$$
Hence the square of the (presumably) longer minus that of the shorter is
$$-2a \cos t+37.\tag{1}$$
Now if $37/(2a)<1$ we can find a first quadrant angle $t$ [in $(0,\pi/2)$] for which $(1)$ holds with equality, and then slightly larger and smaller $t$ make that inequality go one or the other way. Conclude the two distances are not necessarily comparable (without also knowing something more such as the length CS).